# deployment failed without any error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created this small application. I build the application and can see the icon on the emulator when I clicked the icon, the page opens without showing anything and then it closes again without showing any error. I cancelled the build and then it shows the below message in the output window:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\VisualStudioMobileApplication\App3\App3\App3.Android\bin\Debug\com.companyname.app-Signed-Unaligned.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.companyname.app-Signed.apk" 
1>Done building project "App3.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Deploy failed on VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone
1>Process was cancelled
Build has been canceled.
```

It does not give any error. I also put the break point on "OnCreate" method in MainActivity.cs file.The code does not break on that breakpoint even when I click on App3 icon.Below is my code for MainActivity.cs

```
     using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace App3.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "App3", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

The code on MainPage.xaml is below:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App3"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             x:Class="App3.MainPage">

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="30">

        <maps:Map WidthRequest="960" HeightRequest="700" 

       x:Name="MyMap" 

       IsShowingUser="True" 

       MapType="Street" 

       />

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

The code in MainPage.xaml.cs is below:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;



namespace App3
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyMap.MoveToRegion(

                  MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(

                 new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(1)));
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Visual studio 2017 enterprise version 15.6. The build of the entire project is always successful.

Below are my androidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.app" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
  <application android:label="app3.android">
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyD1K1njDAN0"/>
  </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

I really need help to display the map when I click on App3. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Couple of things. It looks like your app is not building, you might want to go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run and change the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" to Detailed - it will give you much more information on what might be wrong with your code. Also, when my code stops building for no reason, I tend to remove "bin" and "obj" folders from the project directory (closing and re-opening visual studio might help as well). Second thing is, you shouldn't post your Google Maps Api key in here

Comment: you need to use adb to look at the device/emulator log

Comment: Check your emulator, it could be problem with your emulator. Open your SDK manager and update the needed tools for your SDK. If this doesn't work.

Try to launch the app using a physical mobile device. If it works, then something is wrong with the emulator/Android SDK

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, if you're using Hyper-V for your emulator, you can try this:

1. Start Hyper V manager
2. Select your machine under 'Hyper-V Manager'
3. Under Virtual Machines, right click on the VS emulator you are
   trying to run your app on, select Settings.
4. Expand the 'Processor' node, select Compatibility.
5. Check the 'Migrate to a physical
   computer with a different processor version' box, click OK and try
   running your app again.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: I am not using Hyper -V as my emulator